# How to pass options in select tag using r-dom in react js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm using `rails` with react-js so here i'm trying to generate select tag like this:

```
  import { form, input, button, span, div,select } from 'r-dom';
  const keywordInput = select({
      name: 'category',
      className: css.keywordInput,
      options: {[
                 {value: 'one', label: 'One'},
                 {value: 'two', label: 'Two'}
               ]}
    });
```

However this doesn't generate options inside select tag also.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So this is a bit late but since I just spent 1 hour struggling on that too and the r-dom documentation ([see here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/r-dom)) is more than succinct, here it is :

In a generic manner, r-dom will generate html tags based on what you coded. Each html tag needs to be a r-dom object. In HTML, a `<select>` tag contains `<option>` tags. Example :

```
<select>
  <option value="km">KM</option>
  <option value="miles">Miles</option>
</select>
```

This means in r-dom, you need to create your `select({})` object, but also your `option({})` objects, one for each option, and then pass them as children of your `select` object. The r-dom documentation (see link above) hints to the following synthax :

```
myComponent = component([properties], [children])
```

For an explicit example of building a `<select>` tag, here are two similar ways to build the list from the above example (note that since `option` is a r-dom object, you also need to import it) :

```
import {select, option} from 'r-dom'

const unitOptionKm = option({
  value: "km",
  label: "KM"
});
const unitOptionMiles = option({
  value: "miles",
  label: "Miles"
});
const selectUnitList = select({
  defaultValue: "km"
},[
  unitOptionKm,
  unitOptionMiles
]);
```

You can have a shorter code with the same result like this :

```
import {select, option} from 'r-dom'

const selectUnitList = select({
  defaultValue: "km"
},[
  option({value: "km",label: "KM"}),
  option({value: "miles",label: "Miles"})
]);
```

To conclude, when using r-dom, we have to see how it is used in html, and each tag must be declared as a r-dom object and passed as a child of its parent tag.